# How to use a key binding within shell script ? (Launch terminator in broadcast mode in background)

Tags: linux, key-binding, broadcast, terminator

I currently use a small shell script to start a `terminator` window as a **background process** which has multiple splits specified with a layout.

```
terminator --layout=My_layout &
```

I want to execute a command to connect to a remote server in all the splits.

When I use this,

```
terminator --layout=My_layout -x command_to_connect arg1 arg2 &
```

only the 1st window is connected.

How do I **broadcast** the message to all the windows from my script?

I have a key binding specified for broadcast. How do I use that when starting a new window?